# OS independent vendor path in Symfony

Tags: php, linux, windows, symfony, twig

I'm developing a Symfony 2.7 application on a Windows machine. I'm using a vagrant VM running Ubuntu Linux (Apache) to run the code. The code is mounted as a synced folder into the Linux system.

When I access my application on the linux host it looks like Symfony is trying to use the Windows path to find the vendor directory:

```
ContextErrorException in /var/www/project/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 131:

Warning: file_get_contents(D:\workspace\project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony
\Bundle\TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory
```

I don't think this is specific to vagrant, It looks like the problem would be the same for anybody working on a remote drive.

How did you guys make this work?

I'm fairly new to Symfony, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue myself. This worked for me...

Add this to your composer.json:

```
"config": {
    [...]
    "vendor-dir": "vendor"
},
```

Update composer and clear Symfony cache.